# compare two generic complex objects java

Tags: java, generics, reflection, compare

My requirement is to compare two objects of the same unknown/generic type. 
The objects are complex. They can contain Lists which can themselves contain Lists.

So, my initial thoughts are to use a Comparator for comparing objects, reflection
for discovering all properties of the bean and some recursion to handle any nested
lists the objects may contain.

or, is there a utility that will do all of that for me, in java?

Comment: If it's 2 object that are different, and you don't know their types, on what criteria will you compare them ?

Comment: @ClementHerreman: that was my first thought too. But the question reads "compare two objects of the **same** unknown/generic type"

Comment: Hi, had not really considered that. Lets assume that there is a predefined list of possible types, String, Integer, Date, List - containing same. Then I can use instanceOf check before doing comparison for each type.

Comment: I believe this is known as a "deep compare".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working on a similar problem. I can confirm that using java reflection you can compare two objects of the same unknown/generic type. I found everything I needed to do so [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/TOC.html). Here is a little rundown on how to do it:

1. Get two objects in a function
2. Determine all on ob1's fields
3. Assuming the objects are of equal type you can use the the one field to get the value out of both objects and compare, like so `field.get(ob1).equals(field.get(ob2)`

However, comparing objects inside of objects is far more difficult. I have no found a solution to it and here is the problem: to compare to items using reflection you need two objects. I have not yet discovered a way to extract an object out of an object of unknown type. Let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bean Utils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) or directly use... [Apache Commons EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

a similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520954/1234198)

**EDITED :**
Please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/867696/1234198). Upon googling I also found [this BeanDiff api](http://beandiff.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3/trunk/docs/javadoc/com/mythosis/beandiff/DiffGenerator.html) which may be useful to you.

Comment: I think this is roughly what i'm looking for but I have an added requirement. Instead of just returning a boolean to say yes/no the objects are equal I need to throw an exception and report on what properties were not equal. So, I'm thinking I needs to implement something similar to EqualsBuilder that throws an exception when the objects are not equal and reports on same.

Comment: The apis like EqualsBuilder do not traverse deeper once a difference is encountered between the two objects. You might need to consider another api or go with your own approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you can ensure all the nested object tree implements Comparable you could use:

```
 public int compareTo(Object o) {
   return CompareToBuilder.reflectionCompare(this, o);
 }
```

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as you already mentioned.

1. Check if both objects are of the same type and
2. Iterate over all variables of object 1

   1. Get the value of the variable in object 2
   2. Call valueOfVariableInObject1.compareTo(valueOfVariableInObject2)

Answer (score 0):

Ewe.  I suppose you could use Reflection to get a list of fields, and go from there.  You would need some complicated code to determine if a given field is a simple or complex type, and burrow into the fields that are complex when you are comparing.

[See this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html) to get you started on getting a list of fields, their names, and their types

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : I'm not a JAVA dev.

I don't think there's a clean way to compare unknown types. Here's what I would do : declare an interface, let's call it ComparableInterface

```
interface ComparableInterface {
    function isEqual(ComparableInterface $a);
}
```

Make all the classes that your unknown object could be an instance of implement this interface. Then use it to compare them.

Any other solutions I can think of would be an ugly hack :/. Also I think if you have to compare thinkg you don't know, you have a problem in your design.